# populate jquerymobile listview from json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I'm new in jQuery mobile development and I can't populate jQuery mobile listview from JSON. I always get an error alert.

here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>listview demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>jQuery Mobile Example</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview"></ul>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">   
              $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function()
              {
                $.ajax
                ({
                      url : "http://localhost/Info.php",
                      dataType: 'json',
                      success: function (result) {ajax.jsonResult = result;alert('OK');},
                      error: function (request,error) {alert('error!');}
                 });
              });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting the json from the info.php file? The error is because you are not getting the json not because of listview

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/PAMY7/

Here's how the HTML will look like:

```
<div data-role="page" id="mypage2">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
         <h1>Listview </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
```

If you just want to populate listview once, you could use `pageinit` event to get it done. if this is supposed to refreshed every single time you reach this page, use `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow`.

You start with something like this :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mypage2", function () {

});
```

Then inside this, you'd make an ajax call and set up an array like this :

```
var typeArray = [];
//make your ajax call here and assign your JSON to typeArray variable//
//typeArray = result in your success function of ajax
typeArray = ["The Great Escape", "12 Angry Men", "Wolf of Wall Street", "Man of Steel"];
```

Assume that `typeArray` is populated by the result of your `ajax` call. Then set up a `ul` & an `li` element which you'll inject into the `dom`:

```
var $ul = $("<ul/>", { "data-role": "listview" }),  $li = $("<li/>");
```

Then, loop over `typeArray` and add those elements to `$li`, which you can add to `$ul`.

```
var i = 0;
for (; i < typeArray.length; i++) {
     $li.clone().html(typeArray[i]).appendTo($ul);
}
```

Append `$ul` to the `<div>` marked with `data-role=content`. After this, you'll have to refresh the `list` like this :

```
$("[data-role=content]", this).html($ul).promise().done(function () {
       $("ul", this).listview().listview("refresh");
});
```

**Note**:

If your `ajax` call is throwing `error`s, then you must use an error handler and find out what error you're facing. Change your error option to this:

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
}
```

and see what error is getting out as an alert. If this is your problem, you must consider re-tagging this question as jQuery, because its got nothing related to jQM.